# Split a class with jquery / js

Tags: jquery, arrays, split

Say I want to grab the number off the back of a class eg: aside300 - I would grab the 300 and assign it to a variable, or aside320 would assign 320 to a variable.
So far I have got the following bit of jQuery:

```
$('[class*=aside]').each(function(index) { // For each of the elements that have a class containing aside
        var asidenum = $(this).attr('class') // Grab all the classes on that element
                              .split("aside") // Split at aside
                              .pop(); // Pop the last item from the array (if aside is the last class then this is great, if not - not so great)
});
```

But, as you can probably see this won't work if you have anything after the 'aside' class - If your classes on the element, for example, are "aside300 anotherclass" - The variable would be '300 anotherclass'

I thought about just splitting at the space, which assigns each class into the array but then I am not sure how to grab just the 'aside' item and split that to grab the number...

If anyone has any pointers, or if I am going about it completely the wrong way, that would be great!

Cheers

EDIT: As people have suggested the data attribute, yup, I would love to use it, it was one of my first thoughts, but unfortunately that's not an option.

Comment: Do you have to use the class attribute? How about using just `aside` and a data-attribute for the value?

Comment: Given your update - just out of curiosity, what prevents you from using it? They're *very* handy so I'm always interested in why people can't use them yet, why in your case?

Comment: CMS constraints and existing code, I would love to use them though and will do in the future!

Comment: @user249950 - gotcha, thanks for satisfying my curiosity :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
var num = $(this).attr('class').match(/\baside(\d+)\b/)[1];
```

But i highly recommend looking into data-attributes and [jQuery's API for them](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: Man, I wish I knew regex... It works but I shall now go figure out what it means haha! I actually looked at using match but due to regex being a foreign language abandoned the idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Felix Kling Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @user249950: Regular expressions are not _that_ hard. They look like "oh my god, i'll never get this", but if you get the basic idea, it is pretty simple ;) This regular expression works like this: The `\b` sequence requires a word boundary at the given position. That means "end of string", "beginning of string" or "whitespace". `aside` requires the string "aside" where it is located. `\d` matches a digit (0-9). The `+` after it requires one or more matches of `\d`. the parenthesis around `\d+` are a match group. This adds everything that is matched in between to the resulting list (offset 1).

Answer (score 4):

If [`data-` attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) are an option, you can do this:

```
<div class="aside" data-aside="320">
```

Then you can do this:

```
$('.aside').each(function() {
  var asidenum = $(this).data('aside');
});
```

Or in jQuery < 1.4.3, use `.attr('data-aside')` instead...you can see from the above it has a few advantages:  simpler code, a CSS class you can use, and a *much* more efficient selector.

This is perfectly valid in HTML5, it's not *valid* but works just fine with no issues in HTML4.

Comment: Yup, I agree that would be much nicer but it has to be the class I'm afraid.

Comment: @user249950 - ah that sucks (for lack of a better description), sorry! I'll leave this here in case others finding your question *can* use this approach.

Comment: Indeed, your answer will be user for others I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regular expression \baside([0-9]+)\b on the classes to capture the number.